# Tkinter surface is displayed wrong in exe

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I'm already trying to fix this for hours but it doesn't work.

I converted my python script to an exe-file. Via pyinstaller and via cx_freeze. But both have the same problem: They display the surface in the wrong way. I include canvas as FigureCanvasTkAgg and when I run it with Spyder it is displayed well. (I tried to place them via .place() and via .pack() ). But with the exe it's all above another and it displays only one of all the canvas (when I enter data for a chart).

Can somebody tell me how to correct this? Is there a way to convert the file to an exe like I can display it via Spyder?

Thank you!!

Displayed in exe: everything is overlapping

[image]

Here displayed how it should be

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a code example? Going off screen shots is not very helpful.

Comment: I have never used spider. Can you run your code in a clean install of Python and get the GUI layout you are expecting?

Comment: Ah thank you. I tried it with cmd and there it looked exactly like in the exe. Even though I still not know where's the difference I can adapt it now and try it correctly.

Comment: GL. Let me know what you figured out. I would be interested to know what the problem was. I have used `cx_freeze` a lot and have not yet run into this problem.

Comment: I think the problem was, that I always run it with spyder. It seems that the resolution differs a bit. Now I just made the canvas smaller and the problem is solved. So it wasn't a problem of pyinstaller or cx_freeze or the converting. 

Another problem was, that I hadn't installed a library so only one chart was shown, which doesn't need that library. 

In the end you can say that the problem is always beyond the screen :D

Comment: In the future I will just try the GUIs with cmd and not the IDEs

Comment: IDE's are fine. I use PyCharm and have used Eclipse and never had a problem with something like this. That said I have seen problems crop up for people using spider but I have never used it myself so I cannot say for sure on that IDE.